# React Native fetching request from API freezes UI

Tags: react-native

I'm able to fetch messages from the API and render them in the component successfully. However, as the number of messages increases, fetching from the API causes the app to freeze and clicking any event (such as selecting a different tab or button) will be only triggered when the request is done.

I've read about using *next-frame* to solve this issue but I'm finding difficulties in how to add it to my code. I'd like to know how to implement *next-frame* inside it.

This is the section of code that fetches messages from the backend:

```
componentWillMount()
{
    /**load user's messages */
    loadmessages() {
        fetch(server + 'view_user_messages.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'text/plain',
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                user_idDB: modulevariables.globaluserid
            })
        }).then((response) => response.text())
            .then((responseJson) => {

                var jsonconvertedrows = JSON.parse(responseJson)
                this.setState({ messagestable: jsonconvertedrows })
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
}
```